# Parsing JSON data containing unicode characters

Tags: json, utf-8, axios

I have <strike>UTF8 encoded</strike> a json file containing unicode characters stored in AWS S3 storage. To be able to download that file from my React project, I've created AWS Gateway API and Lambda function. In the project, I used Axios library to download that file and it seems to be downloaded properly (I check the content with console.log). However, when I parse the file using JSON.parse, I get "bad control character in string literal" error. Checking the content with JSON validators return positive and the http-response header from API Gateway is set properly to "content-type:application/json" and "charset:utf-8". <strike>JSON.parse only works when I delete all UTF8 unicode characters from my file</strike>. When I remove sections that contain unicode characters, I don't even need to use JSON parse. I can access it as an object from my script. This is the content of my json file

```
{
  "en": [
    {
      "Question": "Question 1",
      "Choice": [ "Strongly  Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree Nor Disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree" ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Question 2",
      "Choice": [ "Strongly  Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree Nor Disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree" ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Question 3",
      "Choice": [ "Strongly  Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree Nor Disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree" ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Question 4",
      "Choice": [ "Strongly  Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree Nor Disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree" ]
    }
  ],
  "fr": [
    {
      "Question": "Question 1",
      "Choice": [ "Tout À Fait d'Accord", "d'Accord", "Ni En Désaccord Ni d'Accord", "Pas d'Accord", "Pas Du Tout d'Accord"]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Question 2",
      "Choice": [ "Tout À Fait d'Accord", "d'Accord", "Ni En Désaccord Ni d'Accord", "Pas d'Accord", "Pas Du Tout d'Accord"]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Question 3",
      "Choice": [ "Tout À Fait d'Accord", "d'Accord", "Ni En Désaccord Ni d'Accord", "Pas d'Accord", "Pas Du Tout d'Accord"]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Question 4",
      "Choice": [ "Tout À Fait d'Accord", "d'Accord", "Ni En Désaccord Ni d'Accord", "Pas d'Accord", "Pas Du Tout d'Accord"]
    }
  ],
  "pt": [
    {
      "Question": "Questão 1",
      "Choice": [ "Concordo Plenamente", "Aceita", "Não Concordo Nem Discordo", "Discordar", "Discordo Fortemente" ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Questão 2",
      "Choice": [ "Concordo Plenamente", "Aceita", "Não Concordo Nem Discordo", "Discordar", "Discordo Fortemente" ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Questão 3",
      "Choice": [ "Concordo Plenamente", "Aceita", "Não Concordo Nem Discordo", "Discordar", "Discordo Fortemente" ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "Questão 4",
      "Choice": [ "Concordo Plenamente", "Aceita", "Não Concordo Nem Discordo", "Discordar", "Discordo Fortemente" ]
    }
  ],
  "my": [
    {
      "Question": "မေးခွန်း ၁",
      "Choice": [ "အပြည့်အ၀ထောက်ခံတယ်", "ထောက်ခံတယ်", "ထောက်ခံတယ်လည်းမဟုတ်ဘူး မထောက်ခံတယ်လည်းမဟုတ်ဘူး", "မထောက်ခံဘူး", "အပြည့်အ၀မထောက်ခံဘူး" ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "မေးခွန်း ၂",
      "Choice": [ "Strongly  Disagree", "Somewhat Disagree", "Agree", "Somewhat Agree", "Strongly Agree" ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "မေးခွန်း ၃",
      "Choice": [ "Strongly  Disagree", "Somewhat Disagree", "Agree", "Somewhat Agree", "Strongly Agree" ]
    },
    {
      "Question": "မေးခွန်း ၄",
      "Choice": [ "Strongly  Disagree", "Somewhat Disagree", "Agree", "Somewhat Agree", "Strongly Agree" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT**
This is code responsible for downloading and parsing that file :

```
    let request = {
        host: process.env.AWS_HOST,
        method: 'GET',
        url: process.env.AWS_URL,
        path: process.env.AWS_PATH
    }

    let signedRequest = aws4.sign(request, {
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY
     });


    axios(signedRequest)
        .then(response => {

            console.log(response.data); 

            JSON.parse(response.data); // Error!

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error",error);
        });
```

**EDIT**
I corrected the title to reflect the question I'm asking.

Comment: What editor do you use to edit the file? Is it set to "UTF-8 without BOM"?

Comment: I'm asking because you speak of "UTF8 characters". There are no UTF-8 characters. There are *Unicode* characters. UTF-8 is just one of the many ways of representing Unicode as bytes in a file - it's an encoding. Not every Unicode file is automatically encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: You are right! I confused encoding with charset. Thanks for pointing that out. To answer your question, I use Atom editor and it does not seem to have "with BOM" or "without BOM" option for UTF

Comment: Okay, then you need to show the code that loads the file. Reduce it to a minimal (like five-line) test program that reproduces the error. Also, load the file from disk as a test. Does the same error occur?

Comment: I added the code to my post. I imported the json object locally and I do not have any issue.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out that it was my lambda function causing this issue. The function  reads the file from s3 bucket and encode the data as ascii before returning as response. Fixing it to utf-8 resolve the issue. Thanks @Tomalak for your time.

```
const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
    statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
    body: err ? err.message :  res.Body.toString('utf-8'), // <<-- this line 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Charset': 'utf-8',
        "'Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution and an explanation!